# What should be data source to access ssrs local report using entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, reporting-services

I have made an application with entity framework.now i want to include local ssrs report in this..so please tell me what should i write in **DataSource.Add()**???

```
        EmployeeEntities ent = new EmployeeEntities();
        rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        LocalReport localReport = rptViewer.LocalReport;
        localReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Users\shoaib\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Testing\Report Project5\Report Project5\Report2.rdl";
        localReport.DataSources.Clear();
        rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add("EmployeeDataSet", ent.EmployeeInfoes);Error Occurs
        rptViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score 0):

the code should be

```
rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("EmployeeDataSet", ent.EmployeeInfoes));
```